# Jsoup.parse().body().getAllElements() doubles tags

Tags: java, html, outlook, jsoup

Is there any reason why this JSoup doubles the contents of the body tag here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Jsoup.parse(myHtmlString).body().getAllElements()
}
```

It does just happen for this html code:

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <style> p{margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;} body{font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;} </style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="wordsection1"> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span></p> 
   <div> 
    <div style="padding-top:3.0pt;padding-left:0cm;padding-right:0cm;padding-bottom:0cm;border-left-style:none;border-top-width:1.0pt;border-bottom-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-top-color:#B5C4DF;border-top-style:solid;"> 
     <p class="msonormal"> <b> <span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Von:</span></b><span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;"> Uasdsaa Aasdsaa [mailto:bullet1@left.de] <br><b>Gesendet:</b> Dienstag, 6. August 2013 08:59<br><b>An:</b> Helmut Grashoff (dsfaasas@gmbh.de)<br><b>Betreff:</b> erster Test f&uuml;r die 2.2.1 (mit HTML)</span></p> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
   <p class="msonormal">Erst schauen wir mal, ob die Mail &uuml;berhaupt ankommt.</p> 
   <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
   <p class="msonormal">Und <i> <u>gleichzeitig</u></i> <span style="font-size:18.0pt;">spiele</span> ich noch ein <span style="color:#31859C;">wenig </span> <span style="font-family:Algerian;">mit dieser Zeile</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">Mit freundlichen Gruessen</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="color:#31849B;">Uasdsaa Aasdsaa</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="font-size:9.0pt;">Iasdsaa-Sasdsaa</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">56218 M&uuml;lheim-K&auml;rlich</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
   <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

The result of the above parsing method, not that here is only the content of the body part:

```
<body> 
 <div class="wordsection1"> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span></p> 
  <div> 
   <div style="padding-top:3.0pt;padding-left:0cm;padding-right:0cm;padding-bottom:0cm;border-left-style:none;border-top-width:1.0pt;border-bottom-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-top-color:#B5C4DF;border-top-style:solid;"> 
    <p class="msonormal"> <b> <span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Von:</span></b><span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;"> Uasdsaa Aasdsaa [mailto:bullet1@left.de] Br2nL<b>Gesendet:</b> Dienstag, 6. August 2013 08:59Br2nL<b>An:</b> Helmut Grashoff (asdafsdf@gmbh.de)Br2nL<b>Betreff:</b> erster Test f&uuml;r die 2.2.1 (mit HTML)</span></p> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
  <p class="msonormal">Erst schauen wir mal, ob die Mail &uuml;berhaupt ankommt.</p> 
  <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
  <p class="msonormal">Und <i> <u>gleichzeitig</u></i> <span style="font-size:18.0pt;">spiele</span> ich noch ein <span style="color:#31859C;">wenig </span> <span style="font-family:Algerian;">mit dieser Zeile</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">Mit freundlichen Gruessen</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="color:#31849B;">Uasdsaa Aasdsaa</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="font-size:9.0pt;">Iasdsaa-Sasdsaa</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">56218 M&uuml;lheim-K&auml;rlich</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
  <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
 </div>  
</body>
<div class="wordsection1"> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span></p> 
 <div> 
  <div style="padding-top:3.0pt;padding-left:0cm;padding-right:0cm;padding-bottom:0cm;border-left-style:none;border-top-width:1.0pt;border-bottom-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-top-color:#B5C4DF;border-top-style:solid;"> 
   <p class="msonormal"> <b> <span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Von:</span></b><span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;"> Uasdsaa Aasdsaa [mailto:bullet1@left.de] Br2nL<b>Gesendet:</b> Dienstag, 6. August 2013 08:59Br2nL<b>An:</b> Helmut Grashoff (asfasd@gmbh.de)Br2nL<b>Betreff:</b> erster Test f&uuml;r die 2.2.1 (mit HTML)</span></p> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
 <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
 <p class="msonormal">Erst schauen wir mal, ob die Mail &uuml;berhaupt ankommt.</p> 
 <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
 <p class="msonormal">Und <i> <u>gleichzeitig</u></i> <span style="font-size:18.0pt;">spiele</span> ich noch ein <span style="color:#31859C;">wenig </span> <span style="font-family:Algerian;">mit dieser Zeile</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">Mit freundlichen Gruessen</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="color:#31849B;">Uasdsaa Aasdsaa</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="font-size:9.0pt;">Iasdsaa-Sasdsaa</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">56218 M&uuml;lheim-K&auml;rlich</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p> 
 <p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p> 
</div>
<p class="msonormal"> <span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<span style="color:#1F497D;">&nbsp;</span>
<div> 
 <div style="padding-top:3.0pt;padding-left:0cm;padding-right:0cm;padding-bottom:0cm;border-left-style:none;border-top-width:1.0pt;border-bottom-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-top-color:#B5C4DF;border-top-style:solid;"> 
  <p class="msonormal"> <b> <span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Von:</span></b><span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;"> Uasdsaa Aasdsaa [mailto:bullet1@left.de] Br2nL<b>Gesendet:</b> Dienstag, 6. August 2013 08:59Br2nL<b>An:</b> Helmut Grashoff (asdffasd@gmbh.de)Br2nL<b>Betreff:</b> erster Test f&uuml;r die 2.2.1 (mit HTML)</span></p> 
 </div> 
</div>
<div style="padding-top:3.0pt;padding-left:0cm;padding-right:0cm;padding-bottom:0cm;border-left-style:none;border-top-width:1.0pt;border-bottom-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-top-color:#B5C4DF;border-top-style:solid;"> 
 <p class="msonormal"> <b> <span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Von:</span></b><span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;"> Uasdsaa Aasdsaa [mailto:bullet1@left.de] Br2nL<b>Gesendet:</b> Dienstag, 6. August 2013 08:59Br2nL<b>An:</b> Helmut Grashoff (asdfsad@gmbh.de)Br2nL<b>Betreff:</b> erster Test f&uuml;r die 2.2.1 (mit HTML)</span></p> 
</div>
<p class="msonormal"> <b> <span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Von:</span></b><span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;"> Uasdsaa Aasdsaa [mailto:bullet1@left.de] Br2nL<b>Gesendet:</b> Dienstag, 6. August 2013 08:59Br2nL<b>An:</b> Helmut Grashoff (asdfsdfa@gmbh.de)Br2nL<b>Betreff:</b> erster Test f&uuml;r die 2.2.1 (mit HTML)</span></p>
<b> <span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Von:</span></b>
<span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Von:</span>
<span tahoma","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="" style="font-size:10.0pt;"> Uasdsaa Aasdsaa [mailto:bullet1@left.de] Br2nL<b>Gesendet:</b> Dienstag, 6. August 2013 08:59Br2nL<b>An:</b> Helmut Grashoff (asdfsdf@gmbh.de)Br2nL<b>Betreff:</b> erster Test f&uuml;r die 2.2.1 (mit HTML)</span>
<b>Gesendet:</b>
<b>An:</b>
<b>Betreff:</b>
<p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="msonormal">Erst schauen wir mal, ob die Mail &uuml;berhaupt ankommt.</p>
<p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="msonormal">Und <i> <u>gleichzeitig</u></i> <span style="font-size:18.0pt;">spiele</span> ich noch ein <span style="color:#31859C;">wenig </span> <span style="font-family:Algerian;">mit dieser Zeile</span></p>
<i> <u>gleichzeitig</u></i>
<u>gleichzeitig</u>
<span style="font-size:18.0pt;">spiele</span>
<span style="color:#31859C;">wenig </span>
<span style="font-family:Algerian;">mit dieser Zeile</span>
<p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">Mit freundlichen Gruessen</span></p>
<span mso-fareast-language="DE">Mit freundlichen Gruessen</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p>
<span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="color:#31849B;">Uasdsaa Aasdsaa</span></p>
<span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="color:#31849B;">Uasdsaa Aasdsaa</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="font-size:9.0pt;">Iasdsaa-Sasdsaa</span></p>
<span mso-fareast-language="DE" style="font-size:9.0pt;">Iasdsaa-Sasdsaa</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p>
<span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span></p>
<span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span></p>
<span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">asdsaa</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">56218 M&uuml;lheim-K&auml;rlich</span></p>
<span verdana","sans-serif";mso-fareast-language:de"="">56218 M&uuml;lheim-K&auml;rlich</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p>
<span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span>
<p class="msonormal"> <span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span></p>
<span mso-fareast-language="DE">&nbsp;</span>
<p class="msonormal">&nbsp;</p>
```

I am using Java 6 and Jsoup 1.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious and perfect.

Infact it doesn't double but repeats the `Elements`  as many times as its depth  w.r.t to the reference `Node`

Each and every `Node` under `body` is considered as `Element` including `body`, until it reaches the leaf `Node`.

If you consider the text `<b>Betreff:</b>` It is repeated 7 times since, it is 7 levels below the root (`<body>`)  , and also it is the child with greater depth in the tree.

### `body > div >div > div > p > span >b`